# Include C file in a dart/flutter project

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

In a cross-platform (Android/iOS) project written with [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org) and [Flutter](https://flutter.io), I need to include a C-file and call C-functions from that file. For example, lots of the latest encryption code does not exist in Dart yet. Furthermore, I need to call the C code in dart functions with return values, so I cannot use asynchronous methods, but need to call these functions synchronously.

A [thread about including C/C++ code in Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053) seems to suggest to use [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/). With these, one could use native code of the respective platforms. For iOS, Objective C is a superset of C, and for Android, one would need an additional layer, namely the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/) to use C code. This would not only mean that one needs to write the code twice (which I could live with), but the [platform channels tutorial](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) explicitly says that the platform calls are asynchronous (which breaks things for me).

I found another [thread about native extensions in Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-vm/native-extensions) from 2012 which shows how to include C code in dart, but this appears to be aimed only at command line apps.

It would be strange if there exists no way to synchronously call a C function from flutter. If you have an idea of how to make this happen, you could for a proof of concept consider a trivial C function like this:

```
int inc(int num) {
    return num + 1; 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution regarding this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, there is no way you can do this synchronously. Sorry for breaking your heart.

Comment: No worries, my heart is not that easily broken :-) It's just a lot of code that I will have to rewrite to make it work with the asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 6):

With the latest stable release of the Dart SDK ( [2.5.0](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk) as of writing of this answer ), it's possible to include a C file in your dart/flutter project.

> Dart mobile, command-line, and server apps running on the Dart Native platform can use the `dart:ffi` library to call native C APIs. The ffi name stands for **foreign function interface.**

As of now `dart:ffi` has been released as a preview feature only and the API might encounter breaking changes in the future.

You can take a look at the quick start guide [here](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) or take a look at the [hello world sample](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/master/ffi/hello_world) on Github.

> Furthermore, I need to call the C code in dart functions with return values

Refer to [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/master/ffi/primitives) example if you'd like to pass parameters and get some value in return.